# How to give animation on width change with different classname but for same component

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

what is the best practice to show/hide the side menu with animation? The way I implement works fine but I can't implement the animation. I also shared images so everyone can have some idea.

The answer might be easy but I couldn't fully understand the toggle class efficiently. If I would I should be able to implement transition just by changing the width from the same classname.

Also I am getting this error on console: **Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `className`.**

React code ;

```
const handleSize = () => {
setOpen(!open);   };   return (
<div
  className={"sideBar" + `${open ? " sideBar__show" : " sideBar__hide"}`}
>
  <div className="sideBar__header">
    <div className="menu_buttons" onClick={handleSize}>
      <MenuIcon className="sideBar_icon" />
      <p className={!open && "sideBar_hide__content"}>Menu</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr className="sideBar__divider" />
  <div className="sideBar__content">
    {sideBarContent.map((item) => {
      return (
        <div className="menu_buttons" key={item.name}>
          <item.icon />
          <p className={!open && "sideBar_hide__content"}>{item.name}</p>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
  <hr className="sideBar__divider" />
  <div className="sideBar__footer">
    <Avatar>{firstLetter}</Avatar>
    <p className={!open && "sideBar_hide__content"}>{adminName}</p>
  </div>
</div>   ); };
```

CSS;

```
.sideBar {
  position: fixed;
  left: var(--sidebar-left-margin);
  height: max-content;
  top: calc(var(--header-height) + 10px);
  bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: var(--second-color);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid var(--main-color);
  /* transition: all ease-in 1s; */
}
.sideBar__show {
  width: var(--sidebarOpen-width);
}
.sideBar_hide {
  width: var(--sidebarClose-width);
}
.sideBar_hide__content {
  display: none;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is best practice, this is my currently approach:

```
const handleSize = () => setOpen(!open);
const sideBarClasses = open ? "sideBar sideBar_show : "sideBar sideBar_hide;

  <div className="sideBar__header">
    <div className={sideBarClasses}>
```

Comment: I really like this approach of holding className in a variable. This helps me to shorten my code. Still working on animation ...

Comment: Could you post your animation code on code pen and share it?

Comment: Here is it [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-rgb-qiyjef?file=/src/App.js) . I hope this helps